# How to test Phonegap application on Phonegap emulator

Tags: testing, cordova, phonegap-build

I am using Phonegap build to generate executable files for each platform. Each time I make changes in my code, I have to upload the code on phonegap build and generate new Apk file (for android). I don't want to test on real device,  How can I test my code on phonegap emulator??
[Getting started guides](http://emulate.phonegap.com/) are very confusing for beginners like me. Please help me out.

Comment: Hello OP. I know this is late, but i felt I could share some light on your problem. I do not use the Phonegap emulator, but see my answer [on this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284665/is-there-a-way-to-test-phonegap-build-apps-on-different-platforms/20543625#20543625) Maybe this can help you even further.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the AVD from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html. Click on `DOWNLOAD FOR OTHER PLATFORMS` and choose `installer_r22.2.1-windows.exe` if you are a windows user. Once you have installed it go to the install dir and execute `SDK Manager.exe` and download the virtual device images you need. Then execute `AVD Manager.exe`, create a virtual device and you are ready to go.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want to manage native SDK of any platform for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I Know I'm late but you can use [this](http://emulate.phonegap.com/) to test, then generate your apk when you're done.
Only for **chrome**