# Is there a way to test phonegap build apps on different platforms

Tags: debugging, testing, cordova, phonegap-build

So I developed a phonegap app using Android development sdk. And I used Phonegap build to build my project for Simbian, WebOS, Windows, iOS, and Blackberry.

But I don't have devices for those platforms to test my app on. And I really don't want the headache of setting up those development environments, I mean, that's why they have Phonegap Build right?

I have had complaints from WebOS, Simbian, and Windows that my app doesn't work. And haven't gotten the license gen working on Blackberry (no linux support) or iOS (working on xcode via virtualbox ...).

So is there an easier way? I was thinking of starting a PhoneGap-Test forum where developers could post their binaries for the different devices, and people with other development environments could test your app on say iOS and you in turn test their app on say Simbian.  Does this make sense?

If we get enough developers it could work smoothly. Does anyone know anybody doing this now, or another solution for this? I should add I have tried all the solution listed on the [phonegap wiki](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap) which I could get to work. My app uses the accelerometer, and there seems to be still be a Gap between platforms.

Comment: Did you try [Phonegap Emulate](http://emulate.phonegap.com/) at all?

Comment: Yes, I tried Phonegap Emulate. And all the other debuggers/emulators I could get to work listed on the [phonegap wiki](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap). There is a huge difference between emulating and running on a device. From my experience here.

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a easy way to test out your own code on each plataform.

But you can test your windows phone compilation on Visual Studio. It does **emulate a Windows Phone**. [Here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_getting-started_windows-8_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Windows%208) is a tutorial for you.

You can use [**Ripple**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc) to make some simple testing of your design.
There is for **webOs** a [Emulator](https://developer.palm.com/content/api/dev-guide/tools/emulator.html).

For Symbian... I don't really know. I have a old Symbian phone here, but i never even tested on it - because of a simple question: Do i really need my application on all plataforms? As the application grows, support for all these platforms will be a real challenge. So, why not develop only for your target and/or the major ones? If you develop a Application for Android and IPhone, you will still get a big cut of the market.

That's what i did. It's a less pain to support a webApp that way. Of course, you can buy old refurbished phones just for testing. There is a lot of them at deal extreme. That way you can test specific components, like camera and such.

Good luck.

**EDIT**:

Found something on **Symbian** [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_symbian_index.md.html). There are some good emulators here.
[Here](https://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/develop/simulator/) is something for **BlackBerry**.

Here is something Special, just for you. *[**MobileCloud**](https://www.perfectomobile.com/portal/cms/mobilecloud_platform/platform.html)* allows developers to test their apps using the cloud to release their apps in multiple devices.
May be worth a shot!

***[ANOTHER EDIT!!!]***

Well, here I am again... I'm bringing something new. [**Intel XDK**](http://xdk-software.intel.com/). Intel XDK runs above Cordova.  It is a complete IDE integrated with Ripple, a Editor, and a Designer tool. You can use it as you will for web apps development. With the ripple, you can simulate your web apps across many device profiles, and it compiles using cordova, and the designer tool is really straight-forward and simple.

(Just a reminder: Phonegap also runs above cordova.)

Anyway, Intel did a great job on that one. I liked it very much. We're importing our Phonegap projects to this tool as I post here.

Once again, good luck!

Comment: ya no, that is like super expensive

Comment: Maybe for the company it's not. I do not know if you're working the lone wolf way or what. I just want to help. :) Good luck.

Comment: absolutely, I hate being a lone wolf, but if you've seen my code you'd know why nobody wants to hire me.

Comment: @HPP Maybe you should do some reviewing them? Microsoft virtual academy has content on javascript. And it's free! :) http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/learn-html5-with-javascript-css3-jumpstart-training#?fbid=J2iRmnJw1mx

Comment: Hello, @HPP. I have made another edit. Maybe this can help you? :)